# Is there a way to measure individual parts of an electric field from only one part of it?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-fields, electrons, charge

Let's say I have an electric field made up of charges, and let's say I have the ability to measure a single electron's charge/spin (either positive of negative).

Is there a way that you can measure through this single electron the entire electric field's charge? And if that's even possible, is there a way to measure an individual electron's charges in the same electric field? (the diagram at the bottom should clarify things up).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you can measure the acceleration of the electron you can only conclude the electric field at the place or the path of the electron.
Your " an electric field made up of charges" is a very unusual and wrong phrasing.